# Docker Build : ERROR: failed to solve: executor failed running

Tags: docker, ubuntu, build, apt, ubuntu-22.04

When I'm trying to build a Dockerfile in Ubuntu 22.04, I'm getting this error:

ERROR: failed to solve: executor failed running

`ERROR: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/bash -c apt-get update -qq     && apt-get install -yqq -o=Dpkg::Use-Pty=0     locales build-essential curl unzip autoconf     perl libtool pkg-config sed wget     autoconf-archive git python3 gawk     protobuf-compiler-grpc     && apt-get clean]: exit code: 100`

When I builded the same Dockerfile on macbook it is done.

The docker version on macbook is Docker version 20.10.24, build 297e128
While docker version on linux is Docker version 23.0.3, build 3e7cbfd

I have tried removing docker and Installing it again, but I'm having the same issue. I was able to build "hello-world" image, but I'm not able to build this image.

I tried to build docker image, and expect to get the image.

Complete Error Message:

```
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                           0.4s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                              0.5s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:bookworm                                                                             3.0s
 => CACHED [ 1/12] FROM docker.io/library/debian:bookworm@sha256:35e2ca60775a58ae1637020722a26f0c8ffd792cf7385aa6306677539c363f38              0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                              0.3s
 => => transferring context: 113B                                                                                                              0.0s
 => ERROR [ 2/12] RUN apt-get update -qq     && apt-get install -yqq -o=Dpkg::Use-Pty=0     locales build-essential curl unzip autoconf      220.0s
------                                                                                                                                              
 > [ 2/12] RUN apt-get update -qq     && apt-get install -yqq -o=Dpkg::Use-Pty=0     locales build-essential curl unzip autoconf     perl libtool pkg-config sed wget     autoconf-archive git python3 gawk     protobuf-compiler-grpc     && apt-get clean:                                            
#0 52.87 debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed                                                                  
#0 54.80 Selecting previously unselected package perl-modules-5.36.                                                                                 
#0 54.81 (Reading database ... 6023 files and directories currently installed.)                                                                     
#0 54.81 Preparing to unpack .../0-perl-modules-5.36_5.36.0-7_all.deb ...
#0 55.62 Unpacking perl-modules-5.36 (5.36.0-7) ...
#0 59.59 Selecting previously unselected package libgdbm6:amd64.
#0 59.60 Preparing to unpack .../1-libgdbm6_1.23-3_amd64.deb ...
#0 60.06 Unpacking libgdbm6:amd64 (1.23-3) ...
#0 63.69 Selecting previously unselected package libgdbm-compat4:amd64.
#0 63.69 Preparing to unpack .../2-libgdbm-compat4_1.23-3_amd64.deb ...
#0 63.97 Unpacking libgdbm-compat4:amd64 (1.23-3) ...
#0 66.53 Selecting previously unselected package libperl5.36:amd64.
#0 66.54 Preparing to unpack .../3-libperl5.36_5.36.0-7_amd64.deb ...
#0 67.62 Unpacking libperl5.36:amd64 (5.36.0-7) ...
#0 70.74 Selecting previously unselected package perl.
#0 70.74 Preparing to unpack .../4-perl_5.36.0-7_amd64.deb ...
#0 71.62 Unpacking perl (5.36.0-7) ...
#0 75.20 Selecting previously unselected package autoconf-archive.
#0 75.21 Preparing to unpack .../5-autoconf-archive_20220903-3_all.deb ...
#0 76.63 Unpacking autoconf-archive (20220903-3) ...
#0 86.88 Selecting previously unselected package libmpfr6:amd64.
#0 86.88 Preparing to unpack .../6-libmpfr6_4.2.0-1_amd64.deb ...
#0 89.50 Unpacking libmpfr6:amd64 (4.2.0-1) ...
#0 99.57 Selecting previously unselected package readline-common.
#0 99.57 Preparing to unpack .../7-readline-common_8.2-1.3_all.deb ...
#0 101.0 Unpacking readline-common (8.2-1.3) ...
#0 108.5 Selecting previously unselected package libreadline8:amd64.
#0 108.5 Preparing to unpack .../8-libreadline8_8.2-1.3_amd64.deb ...
#0 108.8 Unpacking libreadline8:amd64 (8.2-1.3) ...
#0 114.4 Selecting previously unselected package libsigsegv2:amd64.
#0 114.4 Preparing to unpack .../9-libsigsegv2_2.14-1_amd64.deb ...
#0 115.8 Unpacking libsigsegv2:amd64 (2.14-1) ...
#0 123.3 Setting up libmpfr6:amd64 (4.2.0-1) ...
#0 125.9 Setting up readline-common (8.2-1.3) ...
#0 127.3 Setting up libreadline8:amd64 (8.2-1.3) ...
#0 128.0 Setting up libsigsegv2:amd64 (2.14-1) ...
#0 137.9 Selecting previously unselected package gawk.
#0 137.9 (Reading database ... 9254 files and directories currently installed.)
#0 137.9 Preparing to unpack .../0-gawk_1%3a5.2.1-2_amd64.deb ...
#0 140.5 Unpacking gawk (1:5.2.1-2) ...
#0 147.2 Selecting previously unselected package liblocale-gettext-perl.
#0 147.2 Preparing to unpack .../1-liblocale-gettext-perl_1.07-5_amd64.deb ...
#0 149.0 Unpacking liblocale-gettext-perl (1.07-5) ...
#0 161.2 Selecting previously unselected package libssl3:amd64.
#0 161.2 Preparing to unpack .../2-libssl3_3.0.8-1_amd64.deb ...
#0 162.7 Unpacking libssl3:amd64 (3.0.8-1) ...
#0 170.5 Selecting previously unselected package libpython3.11-minimal:amd64.
#0 170.5 Preparing to unpack .../3-libpython3.11-minimal_3.11.2-6_amd64.deb ...
#0 170.9 Unpacking libpython3.11-minimal:amd64 (3.11.2-6) ...
#0 179.1 Selecting previously unselected package libexpat1:amd64.
#0 179.1 Preparing to unpack .../4-libexpat1_2.5.0-1_amd64.deb ...
#0 179.4 Unpacking libexpat1:amd64 (2.5.0-1) ...
#0 191.6 Selecting previously unselected package python3.11-minimal.
#0 191.6 Preparing to unpack .../5-python3.11-minimal_3.11.2-6_amd64.deb ...
#0 192.1 Unpacking python3.11-minimal (3.11.2-6) ...
#0 194.6 Setting up libssl3:amd64 (3.0.8-1) ...
#0 198.7 Setting up libpython3.11-minimal:amd64 (3.11.2-6) ...
#0 204.6 Setting up libexpat1:amd64 (2.5.0-1) ...
#0 207.6 Setting up python3.11-minimal (3.11.2-6) ...
#0 209.9 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/__future__.cpython-311.pyc.140214095509440'dpkg: error processing package python3.11-minimal (--configure):
#0 209.9  installed python3.11-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
#0 211.0 Errors were encountered while processing:
#0 211.0  python3.11-minimal
#0 211.0 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
------
ERROR: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/bash -c apt-get update -qq     && apt-get install -yqq -o=Dpkg::Use-Pty=0     locales build-essential curl unzip autoconf     perl libtool pkg-config sed wget     autoconf-archive git python3 gawk     protobuf-compiler-grpc     && apt-get clean]: exit code: 100
```

Comment: could you share the dockerfile, specifically the CMD and ENTRYPOINT lines if it has them. It seems it's running to an issue in that part (if it has it, if not it looks like something else)

Comment: The complete error message would also be helpful; the last line you've included here basically says "it didn't work" but there should be some more details before this.

Comment: I have edited, please find complete error message.